# Python subprocess call throws errors when using find

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x, find, subprocess

I am making a script in `python3` using `call` from the `subprocess` library. The problem that I am having is that this command `find . -mtime +3 | xargs rm -rf` will work perfectly fine when put into the terminal but when I do this:

```py
from subprocess import call
call(["find", ".", "-mtime", "+3", "|", "xargs", "rm", "-rf"])
```

I end up getting an error that looks something like this:

```sh
find: paths must precede expression: |
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec|time] [path...] [expression]
1
```

What I am doing wrong? Please help :-)

Comment: No kidding? If you did run this command in your shell, you wouldn't have files from 3 days ago to test you python script. CAUTION  !!! Don't try this ! It won't even prompt if you want to remove recursively all files and directories modified since 3 days ago. You should change your example for something like a `grep | sort` or even a `grep | kill` example. This one is too destructive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`|` isn't a command argument; it is shell syntax for joining two commands together.

The simplest way to use a pipe is to pass a single string to `subprocess` and let a shell parse it:

```
from subprocess import call
call("find . -mtime +3 | xargs rm -rf", shell=True)
```

In this case, it works nicely because the command line is very simple; nothing needs quoting.

You can set up a pipe in Python, but it's not as succinct as a single `|` character.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p1 = Popen(["find", ".", "-mtime", "+3"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["xargs", "rm", "-rf"], stdin=p1.stdout)
p1.stdout.close()
p2.wait()
```

See the Python documentation for [further reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline).